# Can I import as only for a function, and have the rest imported as they are?

Tags: python, import

Let's say I have a function named "hello" in a module named a, and various other functions. Is it possible to import hello as goodbye, along with the other symbols? I am thinking of something like this, however it's not valid:

```
from a import hello as goodbye,*
```

Comment: `from a import *` is a bad idea in **most** cases. It will completely pollute your current namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import from a, then bind the new name that you want and delete the previous. Something like

```
from a import *
goodbye = hello
del hello
```

Star imports are usually not so good exactly because of namespace pollution.

Answer (score 2):

```
from a import *
from a import hello as goodbye
```

Comment: Won't this keep `hello` accesible as `hello` as well?

Comment: Actually, the second import could really just be `hello = goodbye`, since `goodbye` us already imported.

Comment: @geo: that's what you get...star imports are in general a bad idea...so you may deserve a -1 for asking this :)

Comment: @Geo: You can fix that by using `del hello`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: you mean `goodbye = hello` not the other way around, right?

Comment: @Kimvais: Yes I do - the old switcheroo :)

Answer (score 1):

Next two lines work fine for me:

```
from core.commonActions import click_on_toolbar_tool, wait_toolbar_tool_enabled as x
from core.commonActions import wait_toolbar_tool_enabled as x, click_on_toolbar_tool
```

OR if you need to import all functions you can use:

```
from core.commonActions import *
from core.commonActions import wait_toolbar_tool_enabled as x
```

OR:

```
from core.commonActions import *
x = wait_toolbar_tool_enabled
```

AND if you want hello not to be more available then simply:

```
from core.commonActions import *
x = wait_toolbar_tool_enabled
wait_toolbar_tool_enabled = None # or del wait_toolbar_tool_enabled
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem. In the example of the OP, all symbols from the module get imported, only one of them is renamed.

Comment: Edited to import all and rename one

Comment: This still leaves to original name accessible. @Francesco has proposed a solution that works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
from a import *
goodbye = hello
del hello
```

Would be another way to do it.